# iPhone Developer Community voice over IP

Tags: iphone, collaboration, voip

Anyone know if there exists any Broadcast/Groups system online that allows developers to become connected in real time to be able to voice chat and keyboard chat, specific to their needs, something a little more immediate as opposed to forums/stackoverflow/pm software.

I for example would like to join a voip chat related to mapkit for iPhone... So while I'm working with mapkit for the next few days, I'd like to become connected with likeminded developers, and from there add them to my friends list or something...

Unless I've just missed it, I'm not aware of anything like this...and if it doesn't exist, there's a free startup company idea for someone...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any VOIP chat forum but I do know that there is a text chat rooms option on stackoverflow. You can either create your own chatroom or join one of the existing ones, like:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad